# Present custom alertView/ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to present (with custom animation) a viewcontroller/"alertView" similar to the picture attached when I receive a push notification (voip call).  We currently present a standard alertView which works well, so this will be an update.

I want to create the IncomingCallAlertVC in the storyboard and then populate it with the info I receive from the push notification (name, options, ringtone etc)
I am having some difficulty doing this and has wondering if anyone can give me a hand.

This is how I am trying to present it :

```
let incomingCallAlertVC = IncomingCallAlertVC()
incomingCallAlertVC.displayMessage("MACKLEMORE")
```

And this is the viewcontroller:

```
class IncomingCallAlertVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mylabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen


    }

    func displayMessage(name:String) {
        self.mylabel.text = name

        let delegate:UIApplicationDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!
        let window:UIWindow! = delegate.window!
        window.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        window.rootViewController!.presentViewController(self, animated: false, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.alpha = 1
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        }
    }
```

But I always get:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at

```
self.mylabel.text = name
```

How can I present a ViewController and pass data without using segues ?

[image]

Comment: Presumably, you designed `IncomingCallAlertVC` in a storyboard or .xib file.  In order to have its outlets initialized (`mylabel`), you need to construct it using the storyboard or xib.

Comment: seems, like there is something wrong with the `myLabel`. Does it work, if you remove this line?

Comment: @FelixSFD  It works without the label yes.  I created the ViewController in the storyboard with outlet in the accompanying IncomingCallAlertVC.  I tried to add it several times with different names.  But always the same nil error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initializer for `UIViewController` is `init(nibName:bundle:)`. When you create the view controller instance, you're just creating a blank, dumb instance of the class. Use the designated initializer: `IncomingCallAlertVC(nibName:"whatever", bundle:nil)`.

The other problem you'll run into is that your `myLabel` outlet won't be connected (will be `nil`) until the view is loaded (which only happens the first time you access the controller's `view` property or `loadView` is called manually).

**Update**

Based on your comment to @FelixSFD, you should still use `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` to make the view controller. You don't have to use a segue but if you're creating the assembly from a storyboard, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.  OverCurrentcontext did the trick.
I had to add this:
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext